# Copying strings from main into a strucutre c

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, struct

I have number of strings stored in the 2 dimensional array named "info" and want to copy them into the array "reply" in the "notes" structure. Ive tried doing this using the below for loop but it dosent copy. Im not getting an error, it just dosent copy the strings. I dont know what else to do, can someone give me some advise on what i need to use?

```
struct notes{
   char tasks[40][250];
   char reply[40][250];
};

struct notes store;

#define M 11

int main()
{

    int a, i, k, l, j;
    char info[40][250];


    for( i = 0 ; i < M ; i++){
       strncpy(store.reply[i], info[i], 250);
    }   


}
```

Comment: I assume your real code actually initializes `info`?

Comment: There is not enough information in the question. Post a [mcve].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude info is initialised

Answer (score 0):

Your question starts off with *"I have number of strings stored in the 2 dimensional array named "info""* but we don't actually see this occuring.

Provided that you have `info` initialized with some strings, I see nothing wrong with your code.

Try to avoid the use of "magic" numbers; use `#define` instead.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define NUM 2   //number of strings
#define LEN 25  //length of each string

struct notes{
   char tasks[NUM][LEN];
   char reply[NUM][LEN];
};

struct notes store;
char info[NUM][LEN];

int main()
{
    /* Assign strings to info */
    char *mystring1 = "Hello world";
    strncpy(info[0], mystring1, LEN);
    char *mystring2 = "I love pie";
    strncpy(info[1], mystring2, LEN);

    /* Copy them to store.reply */
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<NUM; i++){
        strncpy(store.reply[i], info[i], LEN);
    }

    /* Print results */
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<NUM; i++){
        printf("%s\n", store.reply[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello world
I love pie
```